# API for rearranging spaces

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it at all possible to programmatically rearrange the spaces in Mission Control?

The answer is probably no, but I'm asking just in case anyone has any insight.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for Spaces/Mission Control.